# What is the best way to put my variable in an Ajax request function

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

Context: I am working on a Spring WEB MVC app using JSP for the view.

In my JSP page i have an input text field which in fact is a jquery daterange picker:

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2017 - 01/31/2017" />
```

I thought in this ajax function I can retrieve the value of my input daterange and pass it to var daterange? like this:

```
function filterByDate() {
                $.ajax({

                    url : 'outbatch',
                    data : ({}),
                    success : function(data) {
                        var daterange = document.getElementById("daterange").value();

                    }
                });
            }
```

And this is my Controller (i did not pase everyting it is too long don't look at the return null i just put it for showing) method who will update my batch and get the information from my model:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/outbatch", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String updateEblnotif(Model model) {

    String out_path = env.getProperty("notif_out");
    List<Doc> doc_list = unmarshal(out_path, "LETTERS");
    System.err.println("jbb*********" + doc_list.size());

    Set<String> formname_set = new HashSet<>();
    `......
     return null`}
```

My question is: Where do I have to pass the variable in my Ajax function call to my Controller? I know that, if I am not mistaken there are several other option parameters that I can pass into an Ajax function like 'data' , 'datafilter' , 'datatype' ? Which is the best way for requesting Dates assuming in my model those are Java Date Objects

Note: I am a very Junior Developer this is my first project. My model uses a DAO with hibernate to map into the database.

Thanks to all of you for your help!

Comment: any update for us ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you should get the value of the parameter in client side so to that you simple have to add `id` attribute to the tag so that your `getElementById` could be useful, try this :

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" id="daterange" value="01/01/2017 - 01/31/2017" />
```

now let's suppose that your function is responsible on retrieving the desired value and send it as parameter to the server side with AJAX, so it's simple :

```
function filterByDate() {
         var daterange = document.getElementById("daterange").value();
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'outbatch',
                    data : {"daterange":daterange}, //here you send the daterange over an Ajax request and by default it's sended with a GET method
                    success : function(data) {
                        alert(data); //here you will see an alert displaying the callback result coming from your spring controller
                    }
                });
            }
```

now we sent the daterange to the controller , so we have to get it back there : to do that you simply can try the following approach :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/outbatch", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String updateEblnotif(Model model,@RequestParam("daterange") String daterange) {
    //so here you're ahving the daterange parameter in controller , if you want to display it in the alert , you can send it in the return like this,
         String date = "the daterange is "+daterange
         return date;
}
```

i hope it was clearly for you.

Comment: Hi @PacMan, sorry for my late reply i just saw your answer this morning. Thank you so much I do now understand how it works! I did test it and it works :)